# R <- Vector - Error in c(vector_item, v$qty) : object 'vector_item' not found

Tags: array, r, vector

Uma dúvida simples,

Como ter o vector (novo) brevemente para evitar:

```
for(v in i$checkout) {
   c(vector, v$name) -> vector
   c(vector_item, v$qty) -> vector_item
}
```

> Error in c(vector_item, v$qty) : object 'vector_item' not found

Comment: `vector_item` já existia? Por que você só atualiza assim no R se o objeto já existir... Tente criar um vetor vazio ou do tamanho de `v$qty` antes do for.

Comment: Pode criar `vector_item <- NULL` ou `vector_item <- c()` antes do ciclo `for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema imediato, corrigir o erro, tal como digo no comentário à pergunta pode criar o vetor

```
vector_item <- NULL
```

ou, alternativamente,

```
vector_item <- c()
```

antes do ciclo `for`.

Mas é muito má ideia extender os vetores dentro dos ciclos, é muito lento porque obriga o R a correr as rotinas de gestão de memória tantas vezes quantas as vezes que o tamanho do vetor muda.

É muito melhor reservar memória antes do ciclo, criando um vetor de resultados com o comprimento adequado. Veja neste exemplo simples a diferença que faz.

```
fun1 <- function(x){
  y <- NULL
  for(i in x){
    y <- c(y, 2*i)
  }
  y
}
fun2 <- function(x){
  y <- numeric(length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    y[i] <- 2*x[i]
  }
  y
}

library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 1e3
x <- 1:n

mb <- microbenchmark(
  mem_extendida = fun1(x), 
  mem_reservada = fun2(x)
)

print(mb, order = 'median')
#Unit: microseconds
#          expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
# mem_reservada  117.966  118.867  135.1909  137.0395  140.407  226.058   100  a 
# mem_extendida 2135.724 2187.807 2698.3200 2217.5420 2277.828 9311.886   100   b

autoplot(mb)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado